# Como puedo hacer que dos arduinos uno sean maestros y esclavos a la vez?

Tags: arduino

Os cuento, necesito conectar 2 arduinos uno entre sí, deben ser esclavos y maestros a
la vez y tengo un problema, es que no sé como programar el segundo arduino para que al recibir un comando específico, devuelva una respuesta en base a ese comando recibido, es decir, que lo ejecute y envíe una respuesta. El canal UART ya lo está usando el esp8266-01 del primer arduino.
He descubierto que podía usar la librería `Wire` y usar el protocolo I2C para comunicar los arduinos entre sí.

Un saludo!

**La comunicación debería ser así:**

esp8266-01 --> arduino uno (procesa) <----> arduino uno (módulo acoplado que ejecuta los comandos y devuelve una señal a cada comando ejecutado)

Os dejo mi código:

**Arduino maestro:**

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include <Wire.h>

SoftwareSerial wifi(2, 3);

void setup()

{
  wifi.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();

  wifi.println("AT+RST");
  delay(2000);
  wifi.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");
  delay(250);
  wifi.println("AT+CWMODE=2");
  delay(250);
  wifi.println("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80");
  delay(250);
}
byte x = "a";

void loop()
{
  while (wifi.available()) {
    String r = wifi.readString();
    String r2 = r.substring(11, 11 + 6);

    if (isNumeric(r2)) {   //comprobar si la señal recibida del esp8266 es un comando, y si es, enviarlo al modulo
      module(r2);
    }
  }
}

void module(String msg) {

  int msg_len = msg.length() + 1;
  char messageByte[msg_len];
  msg.toCharArray(messageByte, msg_len);

  Wire.beginTransmission(4); // transmit to device #4
  Wire.write(messageByte);        // sends six bytes
  Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting
  
  delay(3000);
  
  Wire.requestFrom(4, 6);
  while (Wire.available()) { // slave may send less than requested
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive a byte as character
    Serial.print(c);         // print the character
  }

  delay(500);
}

boolean isNumeric(String str) {
  unsigned int stringLength = str.length();

  if (stringLength == 0) {
    return false;
  }

  boolean seenDecimal = false;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i) {
    if (isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
      continue;
    }

    if (str.charAt(i) == '.') {
      if (seenDecimal) {
        return false;
      }
      seenDecimal = true;
      continue;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

**Arduino esclavo:**

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(4);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

String res = "";

void loop() {

}

void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
  String a = "";
  while (1 < Wire.available()) // loop through all but the last
  {
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    a += c;
  }
  char x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  a += x;

  res = a;
  Serial.println(a);
}

void requestEvent() {
  if(res == ""){
    Wire.write("Error ");
  }else if(res == "000001"){
    Wire.write("MUS001"); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Mira este artículo por Nick Gammon, en la sección [Communicating with other devices](https://www.gammon.com.au/i2c).

Answer (score 0):

Tomado del artículo de Nick Gammon sobre [I2C](https://www.gammon.com.au/i2c)

I2C soporta múltiples masters en un bus, y un equipo en particular puede actuar como master y slave a la vez, pero en direcciones distintas. Asi, puede ser master en una dirección y slave en la otra.

En este ejemplo se usan las direcciones 25 y 42. Cada Arduino registra su propia dirección

```
    Wire.begin(MY_ADDRESS);
```

También registra la función a llamar cuando el otro Arduino quiere enviar datos:

```
    Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
```

Asi, un Arduino puede enviar un stream de datos al segundo, mientras el segundo responde con un mensaje con el valor de la puerta análoga 0. Asi obtenemos comunicación bidireccional.

**Master**

El primer Arduino actua como master en la puerta 25. En esa puerta recibe mensajes via el callback `receiveEvent`. El largo del mensaje se recibe como parámetro, aunque en este caso en particular será siempre 1.

Con cada mensaje recibido, se enciende o se apaga un led según el valor del byte leido (0 o 1, en este caso).

El primer Arduino también actua como cliente del segundo, quien es master en la dirección 42. En cada iteración de `loop`, envia seis mensajes, en cada uno indicando un pin entre 2 y 7, el que debera ser mutado por el segundo Arduino.

```
// Written by Nick Gammon
// February 2012

#include <Wire.h>

const byte MY_ADDRESS = 25;
const byte SLAVE_ADDRESS = 42;
const byte LED = 13;

void setup() 
  {
  Wire.begin (MY_ADDRESS);
  Wire.onReceive (receiveEvent);
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);     
  }  // end of setup

void loop() 
  {
  
  for (int x = 2; x <= 7; x++)
    {  
    Wire.beginTransmission (SLAVE_ADDRESS);
    Wire.write (x);
    Wire.endTransmission ();
    delay (200);
    }  // end of for

  }  // end of loop

void receiveEvent (int howMany)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
    byte b = Wire.read ();
    digitalWrite (LED, b); 
    }  // end of for loop
} // end of receiveEvent
```

**Slave**

El segundo Arduino ejecuta un loop infinito en el cual:

- Lee la puerta análoga 0, lo que retorna un valor entre 0 y 1023.
- Se establece una comunicacion con el master en puerta 25.
- Se compara el valor leido contra 512 y se envia un
  1  si es menor, o 0 si es mayor.
- Se cierra la comunicación.

El segundo Arduino también actúa como master en puerta 42, recibiendo datos vía el callback registrado, `receiveEvent`. El dato que recibe es un número de pin, que es mutado de estado (ON->OFF, OFF->ON), encendiente o apagando un LED conectado a ese pin.

El largo del mensaje (número de pines a mutar) se recibe como parámetro `howMany`, pero en este ejemplo cada mensaje contiene un pin.

```
    // Written by Nick Gammon
    // February 2012
    
    #include <Wire.h>
    
    const byte MY_ADDRESS = 42;
    const byte OTHER_ADDRESS = 25;
    
    void setup () 
      {
      Wire.begin (MY_ADDRESS);
      for (byte i = 2; i <= 7; i++)
        pinMode (i, OUTPUT);
      Wire.onReceive (receiveEvent);
      }  // end of setup
    
    void loop() 
      {
      int v = analogRead (0);
      Wire.beginTransmission (OTHER_ADDRESS);
      Wire.write (v < 512);
      Wire.endTransmission ();
      delay (20);
      }  // end of loop
    
    // called by interrupt service routine when incoming data arrives
    void receiveEvent (int howMany)
     {
      for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        {
        byte c = Wire.read ();
        // toggle requested LED
        if (digitalRead (c) == LOW)
          digitalWrite (c, HIGH);
        else
          digitalWrite (c, LOW);
        }  // end of for loop
      }  // end of receiveEvent
```